# Uppercase ascii character in zig

Tags: ascii, zig

Given a character (`u8`) in zig, how can I make sure it is in ASCII uppercase?

Does the standard library provide helper functions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std.ascii.toUpper(c)`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.toUpper)

In general, the standard library provides the following functions:

- [`std.ascii.isUpper`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.isUpper)
- [`std.ascii.toUpper`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.toUpper)
- [`std.ascii.upperString`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.upperString)

And the corresponding functions for lowercase letters:

- [`std.ascii.isLower`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.isLower)
- [`std.ascii.toLower`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.toLower)
- [`std.ascii.lowerString`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:ascii.lowerString)

Here is some example usage:

```
const std = @import("std")
const expect = std.testing.expect;

const upper_a: u8 = 'A';
const lower_a: u8 = 'a';

const mixed_str: []const u8 = "AbCd";
var out_str = [_]u8{'0', '0', '0', '0'};

try expect(std.ascii.isUpper(upper_a));
try expect(std.ascii.toUpper(lower_a) == upper_a);
try expect(std.mem.eql(u8, std.ascii.upperString(&out_str, mixed_str), "ABCD"));
try expect(std.mem.eql(u8, &out_str, "ABCD")); // upperString writes to out_str

try expect(std.ascii.isLower(lower_a));
try expect(std.ascii.toLower(upper_a) == lower_a);
try expect(std.mem.eql(u8, std.ascii.lowerString(&out_str, mixed_str), "abcd"));
try expect(std.mem.eql(u8, &out_str, "abcd")); // lowerString writes to out_str
```